# Retrieve printing data from old security system via DB25/LPT with Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, printing

As a volunteer for a charity, I've been tasked with managing an old security system for the building. The security system outputs the security logs to an old dot matrix printer continuously. This has been a waste of paper and ink. I have a Raspberry Pi and a breadboard (plus jumpers) laying around. I can map the DB25 pins to my RPi GPIO with a step down from 5V->3.5V. I'm just not sure how to handle the data over the 8 data channels on the DB25.

How does print data get sent over the pins? How can I output it to a text file? I'm guessing it is using ASCII, but I'm not exactly sure how to take the data feed from the DB25 cable and translate to ASCII. I believe the security system uses LPT to output.

Any direction would be great.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I suggest to titel differently; after all you're not trying to emulate a printer but to retrieve (for lack of a better word) data that is sent to a printer.

Comment: Is that more accurate? I wasn't sure how to word it originally.

Comment: Yeah, good question ;) Coming to think of it maybe the solution includes issues that could be phrased as emulation. I have no idea - and as a non-native speaker I struggle with fitting words to a larger extent.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to verify the "believe" that the system uses LPT to output the data since that not only determines the protocol (which in case of LPT is application dependent) and therefore heavily influences how to interpret the data but also pin out and maximum signal voltage levels. It would be highly advisable to check on those voltage levels before connecting the Pi with a voltage divider meant for a certain level. If searching the web does not yield any useful results on the hardware specifications you'll have to do it the hard way: sniff data and control lines it while it's operating with the current printer.

LPT obviously has 8 data lines, 4 output control lines and 5 input control lines; which however - as protocols could be application specific - might not necessarily be used in total. So it is important to figure out what is used when and how. The sniffing could be done using a digital scope or - since you have the Pi - something like the [Piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html). People report to have used it with sample rates up to 1 MHz; so lets hope your system is not using EPP/ECP with a bitrate of up to 2 MHz.

So if got a scope with at least two digital channels the work is pretty much straight forward (prepare to spend a night or two anyway). Connect one data line and one control line and check what they do. The more channels you can observe at the same time the easier it gets to figure out the big picture. Try to understand how data and control lines work. After that it should be possible to interpret it the data lines as characters and so forth.

The most important control line will be */STROBE* as it latches the data lines; that is: the source (the mysterious security system) sets the data lines according to the character it wants to transmit and triggers the strobe line to signal the receiver to read the bits now. Depending on the smartness of the source it might be necessary for your Pi to emulate the behaviour of the printer; especially the *ACK* and */BUSY* signals that might be used to signal that the printer is ready to receive new data. (All is getting more complicated at EPP/ECP modes which are bi-directional.)

Comment: Excellent response. I'll do some more research on the security system and be prepared to get my scope out to do some sniffing. I'll update on the progress.

Comment: If you know the make and model of the printer a google may reveal its interface details.